# Syntax error near unexpected token when installing Yara

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configure, automake

Hi I'm a beginner in Linux and I was about to install Yara (yara-3.2.0) on my Linux 12.04 running on 32-bit machine.

It's all good until I try to configure using ./configure command which results in this error:

```
checking for SHA256_Final in -lcrypto... yes
./configure: line 12735: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./configure: line 12735: `ACX_PTHREAD('
```

I've been searching searching to solve this but nothing good happened. Would anybody help me point anything I could do to solve the errror? Thanks in advanced, any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use  "autoreconf -i" instead ./configure.

Comment: I did "autoreconf -i --force" and did "./configure" again, and it worked now. Thanks!